# Bash delete line beetwen two pattern containing "/"

Tags: bash, sed

I've a problem : I would like to be able to delete lines beetwen two pattern in a file.

For example be able to delete the line equals to "line 1" beetwin "blablabla++" and "blablabla--"

```
line1
blablabla++
line1
line2
line3
blablabla--
line1
```

I've found a way to do it with sed :

```
sed '/blablabla++/,/blablabla--/{/line1/d}' ./file
```

It is working great. But the thing is that in my real file is more like :

```
line1/script
blablabla++
line1/script
line2/script
line3/script
blablabla--
line1/script
```

How could i do that ?

### EDIT

I've choosen a bad example.

The thing is that i don't know what the line that i need to delete will be (the line will be sent as parameter). But i know one thing for sure is that they will contain "/" characters.

The thing is that when i do this :

```
sed '/blablabla++/,/blablabla--/{/$1/d}' ./file
```

The "/" that $1 contain will mess up with my sed.

Comment: it works, second `line1/script` got deleted

Answer (score 2):

You made a bad example, because your sed cmd works both input files. I guess you want to match a pattern containing `/` with sed.

If you want to match something with literal `/`, you can escape those `/`s, however, it makes the codes not so easy to read, particularly you have many `/`s wanted to be matched, you can use `\[c]pattern[c]` here `[c]` could be any char. For example:

```
kent$  cat f
//one//
blablabla++
//one//
//one two//
//one three//
blablabla--
//one//

kent$  sed '/blablabla++/,/blablabla--/{\@//one//@d}' f
//one//
blablabla++
//one two//
//one three//
blablabla--
//one//
```

In above example, `\@//one//@` is the pattern matching part.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I didn't ask the good question so i've edited the first post.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the the `/` character in `line1/script` as below:-

```
$ sed '/blablabla++/,/blablabla--/{/line1\/script/d}' file
line1/script
blablabla++
line2/script
line3/script
blablabla--
line1/script
```

Or probably do an in-place edit with a backup stored, using the `-i` flag.

Another possible solution with `awk`

```
$ awk '/blablabla++/,/blablabla--/{if ($0 ~ /line1\/script/) next }1' file
line1/script
blablabla++
line2/script
line3/script
blablabla--
line1/script
```

The trick when using the `awk` solution is as soon as the pattern is met `$0 ~ /line1\/script/` we are skipping the line from printing using `next` for the next line to be considered.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I didn't ask the good question so i've edited the first post.

Answer (score 0):

To include backslashes in a `sed` regular expression you can either **escape** them, as in `/line1\/script/`, or use a different character for the regex delimiter, as in `#line1/script#`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I didn't ask the good question so i've edited the first post.